# How are chef firewall rules applied to firewalld in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, firewalld, chef

I am using chef [firewall cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firewall) in the following way:

```
firewall 'default'

firewall_rule 'ssh' do
    port 22
end
```

It configures firewalld internally by writing commands like this to `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld-chef.rules`:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 50 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'ssh' -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter INPUT 50 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'ssh' -j ACCEPT
```

However, after `systemctl restart firewalld`, these changes are not applied. I lack experience with Linux network configuration, so I don't know how can I continue. Is there an easy way to set this file to run with firewalld start? Am I doing something wrong in my recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall cookbook is using `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld-chef.rules` to track the state of the firewall rules. It builds the list of commands it should run, and if the list is different than the contents of that file, it reapplies the whole file by clearing the ruleset and then running each command in the file. It doesn't necessarily run that file directly.

We had someone contribute the original logic in this recipe, so I couldn't tell you much more about the way they are using it, but running the `:save` action seems to be the intended way to ensure the rules are permanent. If you're trying to be sure the rules are applied on startup, try running the firewall resource's `:save` action after all of the firewall_rule(s) are applied.